# Get ClientId and UserId from Google analytics by Reporting API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I wanna collect all userId and clientId from GA.

I can see userId in dashoboard:

[image: Custom options]

but I can't find how get same info from APi for All user.
How I can do that with Reporting API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserId` and `ClientID` are custom dimensions. So use `ga:dimensionXX` and replace XX with indexes of your custom dimensions.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/